# There are $2^{63}$ different outcomes of a $64$ team single-elimination tournament such as the NCAA basketball ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

There are $2^{63}$ different outcomes of a $64$ team single-elimination tournament such as the NCAA basketball tournament. Prove that a single-elimination tournament with $2^n$ teams has $2^{2^n-1}$ different outcomes. Hint: Use induction.
Basis step: When n = 1, 2 n = 21 = 2 teams.
              2^(2^1-1) = 21 = 2 outcomes.
                  Therefore, P(1) is true. 
    Induction Hypothesis: Suppose P(K) is true for some positive integer K.
Then a tournament with 2k teams has 2^(2^k-1) different outcomes.
We want to show P(K+1) is also true.
This is all I have right now.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you using the hint?

Comment: Basis step: When n = 1, 2 n = 21 = 2 teams.
           2^(2^1-1) = 21 = 2 outcomes.
            Therefore, P(1) is true. 
 Induction Hypothesis: Suppose P(K) is true for some positive integer K.
Then a tournament with 2k teams has 2^(2^k-1) different outcomes.
This is what I have so far

Comment: @JohnPan:  Edit that work into your Question.

Comment: That's a great start! What comes next? Where did you get stuck at?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I am trying to prove that 2^k teams will have 2^(2^(k+1)-1) outcomes. I am thinking about how many more outcomes will be added when there is one more team than 2^k teams. I kinda just got stuck here.

Comment: Because the question asks about $2^n$ teams, you should be thinking about how it changes when you go to a tournament with $2^{n+1}$ teams.  That is easier because the structure of the tournament is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  think of the rounds of the tournament.  After you play the first round, you have a tournament with one fewer round.  How many results are there in the first round?

Aside:  Induction is the wrong tool here.  As one team is eliminated each game, a tournament with $2^n$ teams must have $2^n-1$ games.  Each game has two results, so there are $2^{2^n-1}$ sets of results.  This does not require the number of teams to be a power of $2$.

Comment: 64 results in the first round

Comment: That depends on the number of teams.  For a $64$ team tournament it is much higher.  How many games are there?

Comment: 2^16 results in the first round

Comment: That is correct for $64$ teams.  If you write it in terms of $n$ it will suggest the induction.